# Postgres: Transform Continous Rows Into a Discrete Rows

Tags: postgresql

I'm not sure wether the title is correct . I've spent some time to find the best title suited for this case.

Let say. I have data in this format:

```
| room |     changes      |   created_at    |
|------|------------------|-----------------|
| A    | [free, occupied] | 2021-11-1 18:00 |
| B    | [free, occupied] | 2021-11-1 20:30 |
| B    | [occupied, free] | 2021-11-1 23:30 |
| A    | [occupied, free] | 2021-11-2 00:15 |
| B    | [free, occupied] | 2021-11-2 01:00 |
```

The output required will be

```
+------+----------+-----------------+
| room | occupied |   Period        |
+------+----------+-----------------+
| A    | NO       | 2021-11-1 18:00 |
| B    | NO       | 2021-11-1 18:00 |
| A    | NO       | 2021-11-1 19:00 |
| B    | NO       | 2021-11-1 19:00 |
| A    | YES      | 2021-11-1 20:00 |
| B    | NO       | 2021-11-1 20:00 |
| A    | YES      | 2021-11-1 21:00 |
| B    | NO       | 2021-11-1 21:00 |
| A    | YES      | 2021-11-1 22:00 |
| B    | NO       | 2021-11-1 22:00 |
| A    | YES      | 2021-11-1 23:00 |
| B    | YES      | 2021-11-1 23:00 |
| A    | YES      | 2021-11-2 00:00 |
| B    | YES      | 2021-11-2 00:00 |
| A    | NO       | 2021-11-2 01:00 |
| B    | YES      | 2021-11-2 01:00 |
| A    | NO       | 2021-11-2 02:00 |
| B    | YES      | 2021-11-2 02:00 |
+------+----------+-----------------+
```

The output generated using this logic:

- When during that period. the room is changed to `occupied`. results.occupied will be `YES`
- when during that period. no changes, the change is taken from the previous change.
- When during that period. the room is changed from `occupied` to `free`. The next period (next row) results."occupied" will be `NO`

Answer (score 1):

First some comments about your question :

- some *period* values in your output doesn't correspond to the *created_at* values in your table
- the *id* column in your output doesn't relate to the *id* column in your table because half of the output rows don't correspond to a row in your table, ie their *id* value can't be determined
- the *occupied* value for the first period value in your output can be set up for the associated room (A) in your table but not for the others (B), so here an arbitrary value must be set up

Then I propose you a query which implements the following rules :

- When the *room* is changed to *occupied*, then *occupied* = "YES" for *period* = *created_at*
- when no change, ie the row doesn't exist in *your_table* for the given *(room, period)* of your output, the *occupied* value is copied from the previous rows with the same *room* and the most recent *created_at* value
- When the room is changed to *free*, then *occupied* = "NO" for *period* = *created_at*

This query may provide a result slightly different from your expectation, but it can be easily adjusted.

see the [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/25b94/7)

```
SELECT t.id -- may be NULL according to the LEFT JOIN and this is a gap with the expected result as presented in the question
     , r.room
     , CASE
         WHEN t.room = r.room AND t.changes = '[free, occupied]'
         THEN 'YES'
         WHEN t.room = r.room AND t.changes = '[occupied, free]'
         THEN 'NO'
         WHEN ( jsonb_agg(t.changes)
                         FILTER (WHERE t.room = r.room)
                         OVER (PARTITION BY r.room ORDER BY p.created_at ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
              )->>-1 IS NOT DISTINCT FROM '[free, occupied]'
         THEN 'YES'
         ELSE 'NO'
       END AS occupied
     , p.created_at AS period
  FROM 
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (created_at) created_at
         FROM your_table
     ) AS p
 CROSS JOIN
     ( SELECT DISTINCT ON (room) room
         FROM your_table
     ) AS r
  LEFT JOIN your_table AS t
    ON t.room = r.room
   AND t.created_at = p.created_at
 ORDER BY p.created_at, r.room
```

In the result, the *id* column corresponds to the *id* value in *your_table*. So this *id* is NULL when the output row doesn't correspond to any rows in *your_table*.

Comment: The id is indeed confusing and I'm removing it as this is not part of question, but a framework artifact.